# Anchor in URL when using Symfony's redirect function

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm using

```
$this->redirect('route', array('id' => $id));
```

but I need to be able to put "#" anchor at the end but I can't find a way of doing that. Any ideas?

The code

```
$this->redirect('route', array('id' => $id));
```

returns /route/id/5 but I want to be able to create /route/id/5#anchor7

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route', array('id' => $id)) . '#anchor7');
```

---

UPDATE:

In Symfony 3.2 you can do this:

```
// generating a URL with a fragment (/settings#password)
$this->redirectToRoute('user_settings', ['_fragment' => 'password']);
```

See https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements

Comment: So.. you took my own answer and put your name on it?

Comment: I dont see your answer @gX.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9054865/revisions and http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5694244/revisions

Comment: @gX This is now a very old question and answer, and I was in my less experienced days on SO. I was probably going through unanswered questions and your one came up because your answer was posted as a comment _not_ an answer. [The correct etiquette for me would have been to post as community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/582278) so I'm sorry for not doing that. From your side, in future make sure you post answers as answers, even if it's [an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Feel free to post another answer here, and I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I had written in the original question: 'StackOverflow wouldn't let me post it as an answer since I'm a "new user"'

Answer (score 2):

Similar but

```
$this->redirect('@routename?id='.$id.'#anchor7');
```

Works fine in Symfony 1.4 and seems slightly simpler solution

Answer (score 2):

Using router :

```
$router->generateUrl('awesome_route') . '#comment-2';
```

This method is used by Fabien Potencier : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3910#issuecomment-5110238